# Is it possible to have two wordpress blogs on the one dashboard?

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently working on a large wordpress website, and would like to start another one, a far simpler one, one or two pages for example. I have a personal account with WP for this website so I was wondering if it was possible to add another website to this account?

Comment: It sounds like you might be talking about wordpress.com instead of wordpress.org?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DO you mean something like ***multisite***? Running two wordpress sites under same *network admin* with seperate dashboard for each of them?

If so then please take a look around https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Comment: The way they have phrased the question makes me think they're using WordPress.com in which multi sites are not an option. But still a good answer.

Comment: No problem pal. Hope you figured out something.